# Is plist file in 'Copy Bundle resource' Read-Only?

Tags: ios, plist

I create plist file, and successfully read data.

But I couldnt write to file. 
(for example, change boolean value NO to YES.
NSMutableDictionaty's writeToFile do not work)

file path is like below.

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Setting" ofType:@"plist"];
```

and I write value like this way.

```
 [myDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"isFirst"];
 [myDict writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Is plist file in 'Copy Bundle resource' Read-Only ?

Comment: the files in the app-bundle are __always read-only__; for everything else you need to use the `Documents/` folder for instance, where you can write anything into freely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a bundle is ALWAYS read only

## 'workaround'

copy the file to the App's Documents directory. There it is R/W

#### pseudo-code for opening the file:

```
path = filePathInDocumentsFolder
file = read(path)
if(!file) {
    copy(plistFromBundle to path)
    file = read(path)
}
```